# How to get the result in Facebook Graph Api Explorer.? Getting error message (#15) This method must be called with an app access_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was Unable to get the search result in Facebook Graph Api Explorer For Topic search API. I am getting the following error. I also have the access token included.[image]

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 15,
    "fbtrace_id": "CJiZqVSATXu"
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error message actually contains the problem. You're not using an **App** Access Token, but seemingly an User Access Token (from the Access Token structure in your screenshot).

You must select an app of yours in the upper right *Applications* dropdown, and then select *Get App Token* in the dropdown below.

Still, that will probably not help much in this case. Are you aware that only **whitelisted apps** can use the Topic Search API?

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mediasolutions/topic_search/v2.5

Comment: Thank you for the answer . but  Get App Token is disable. and I am not aware of the whitelist apps .

Comment: That *Get App Token* is disabled is probably because you didn't create an app yourself yet. Concerning the whitelisting, that is stated in the docs I linked. You won't be able to access this functionality with your own apps. Only so-called media partners have access (they pay for it)

Comment: From the partners: Contact them and pay (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mediasolutions/partners). From FB: Unless you're a well-known company I guess the chances are non-existing

Comment: Is there any alternative solution to do the same without paying to the partners.?